# Does anyone know why my program stop pushing to the stack

Tags: c++, stack

Im trying to solve 8 puzzle using a stack. this code is only to know if the
program can do it
.
The program iterates the first string, and does the job, but after pushing the 2 new strings. it just pop them but doesnt continue with the functions.

anyone have an idea what can i do?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "stack.cpp"

using namespace std;

bool checkFound(string meta,string aVer);
string converArretoString(STACK <string> stack, string ac);
void crearPosibilidad(STACK <string> open,string ac);
void checkRow(STACK <string> stack, int actual[3][3],int row,int col);
void checkCol(STACK <string> stack, int actual[3][3],int row,int col);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    string meta="012345678";
    string actual="120345678";
    STACK <string> state;
    STACK <string> ustate;
    STACK <string> steps;

    state.push(actual);
    while (!state.empty())
    {   
        actual.clear();
        actual=state.pop();
       // cout<<actual<<endl;
        if(checkFound(meta,actual))
        {   
            cout<<actual;
            cout<< "lo encontramos";
            return 0;
        }

            //cout<<actual<<endl;
            ustate.push(actual);
          crearPosibilidad(state,actual);

    }
 return 0;
}
//checa si se encontro la solucion
bool checkFound(string meta,string aVer)
{
    if(aVer==meta)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
//creara los posibles escenarios
void crearPosibilidad(STACK <string> state,string ac)
{
    int act [3][3];
    int i=-1;
    int col=0;
    int ren=0;
    string a;
    for (int r = 0; r<3; r++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<3;c++)
        {
            i++;
           a=ac[i];
            act[r][c]=stoi(a);
            if (act[r][c]==0)
            {
                cout<<r<<endl;
                cout<<c<<endl;
                ren=r;
                col=c;
            }
        }
    }
    checkCol(state,act,ren,col);
    checkRow(state,act,ren,col); 
}

string converArretoString(int actual[3][3])
{
    string temp;
    ostringstream conver;
    for(int r=0;r<3;r++)
    {
        for(int c=0;c<3;c++)
        {
            conver<<actual[r][c];
        }
    }
    temp=conver.str();
    cout<<temp<<endl;
    return temp;
}
void checkRow(STACK <string> stack, int actual[3][3],int row,int col)
{
    int temp;
    string tems;
    if(row==0)
    {
        //mover abajo
        temp=actual[row+1][col];
        actual[row][col]=temp;
        actual[row+1][col]=0;
        tems=converArretoString(actual);
        //cout<<tems<<endl;
        if(!stack.search(tems))
        {
          //  cout<<tems<<endl;
            stack.push(tems);
        }
        //original
        temp=actual[row][col];
        actual[row+1][col]=temp;
        actual[row][col]=0;
    }
    if(row==1)
    {   //moverabajo
        temp=actual[row+1][col];
        actual[row][col]=temp;
        actual[row][col]=0;
        tems=converArretoString(actual);
        //cout<<tems<<endl;
        if(!stack.search(tems))
        {
           // cout<<tems<<endl;
            stack.push(tems);
        }
        //mover arriba
        temp=actual[row][col];
        actual[row][col]=actual[row-1][col];
        actual[row+1][col]=temp;
        actual[row-1][col]=0;
        tems=converArretoString(actual);
        //cout<<tems<<endl;
        if(!stack.search(tems))
        {
           // cout<<tems<<endl;
            stack.push(tems);
        }
        //original
        temp=actual[row][col];
        actual[row-1][col]=temp;
        actual[row][col]=0;

    }

    if(row==2)
    {
        //mover arriba
        temp=actual[row-1][col];
        actual[row][col]=temp;
        actual[row-1][col]=0;
        tems=converArretoString(actual);
        //cout<<tems<<endl;
        if(!stack.search(tems))
        {
           // cout<<tems<<endl;
            stack.push(tems);
        }
        //original
        temp=actual[row][col];
        actual[row-1][col]=temp;
        actual[row][col]=0;
    }


}

void checkCol(STACK<string> stack, int actual[3][3],int row, int col )
{
    int temp;
    string tems;
    if(col==0)
    {

        //mover derecha
        temp=actual[row][col+1];
        actual[row][col]=temp;
        actual[row][col+1]=0;
            //put the generated child on the queue
        tems=converArretoString(actual);
        //cout<<tems<<endl;
        if(!stack.search(tems))
        {
           //cout<<tems<<endl;
            stack.push(tems);
        }
            //return to the orginal
        temp=actual[row][col];
        actual[row][col+1]=temp;
        actual[row][col]=0;

    }//if
    if(col==1)
    {
        //move right
        temp=actual[row][col+1];
        actual[row][col]=temp;
        actual[row][col+1]=0;
        tems=converArretoString(actual);
        //cout<<tems<<endl;
        if(!stack.search(tems))
        {
            //cout<<tems<<endl;
            stack.push(tems);
        }

        //mover izquierda
        temp=actual[row][col];
        actual[row][col]=actual[row][col-1];
        actual[row][col+1]=temp;
        actual[row][col-1]=0;

        tems=converArretoString(actual);
        //cout<<tems<<endl;
        if(!stack.search(tems))
        {
            //cout<<tems<<endl;
            stack.push(tems);
        }
        //orginal
        temp=actual[row][col];
        actual[row-1][col]=temp;
        actual[row][col]=0;
    }

    if(col==2)
    {

        //mover izquierda
        temp=actual[row][col-1];
        actual[row][col]=temp;
        actual[row][col-1]=0;
        tems=converArretoString(actual);
       // cout<<tems<<endl;
        if(!stack.search(tems))
        {
           //cout<<tems<<endl;
            stack.push(tems);
        }
            //orginal
        temp=actual[row][col];
        actual[row][col-1]=temp;
        actual[row][col]=0;

    }

}
```

Comment: Without knowing in the implementation of the `STACK` feature you are using, it is not possible to tell how it behaves. However, assuming `stack.push()` is known to work, then I suggest to consider under what conditions `!stack.search(tems)` is false, as well as if your `if (row)` and `if (col)` type checks are happening as you want them too.

Comment: Try debugging your program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about passing your `STACK`'s by reference?

With your actual code, `converArretoString()`, `crearPosibilidad()`, `checkRow()` and `checkCol()` are receiving `STACK<std::string>` variable by value. So they receive copies of stacks that are destroyed exiting by the function.

When, in `checkRow()` and in `checkCol()`, are pushed values

```
stack.push(tems);
```

the pushed values are lost exiting by the function.

I suggest to change the function signatures in this way

```
string converArretoString(STACK <string> & stack, const string & ac);
void crearPosibilidad(STACK <string> & open,string ac);
void checkRow(STACK <string> & stack, int actual[3][3],int row,int col);
void checkCol(STACK <string> & stack, int actual[3][3],int row,int col);
```

Other suggestion (without correlation with your problem): when possible, pass your variable by const reference. Example: your `checkFoud()` receive 2 `std::string` by copy; the function don't modify the values, so you can pass the strings by const reference, avoiding unuseful copies; something like

```
bool checkFound (const string & meta, const string & aVer)
 { return aVer == meta; }
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Comment: thanks it worked out. i still don't understand how does & works. but thank you.
p.s dont worry mine is even worst